# Geting an instance of Windows Control (dialog window) by its handle

Tags: delphi, handle

I called some dialog window in delphi. I'm trying to get refference to it, bu encountering problem. Those controls are not VCL so I can't use FindWindow(handle): TWinControl

Is there method that returns proper window control?

Is there any chace That I would be able to gather from dialog window info like:

*number of controls on dialog window
*names, text, classnames of controls on dialog window

Comment: You cannot get a `TWinControl` or indeed any VCL instance from this window handle. You can call `EnumChildWindows` to enumerate of the children of the top level dialog window. And then you can query them for class name and so on. The main Win32 APIs you need are `GetClassName` and `GetWindowText`.

Comment: You need to write `@EnumChildProc` because Windows.pas defines the enum proc as a typeless `Pointer`! I personally would define my own `import` that had a typed callback procedure to make sure I got it right.

Comment: You should post it as an answer mate, that will do in my cause. Thanks again

Comment: Are you suggesting I post an answer? I won't do that because Rob's answer says the same thing as my comments, just a little expanded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there isn't really a VCL control representing the dialog box, then you cannot manufacture one out of nothing. VCL controls create and assume responsibility for their corresponding Windows controls, but if the Windows controls already exist, then there is no way to "wrap" them into new VCL objects.

You'll just have to operate on the window handles directly instead. You can use them to gather whatever information you want.